# How do I convert dot-delimited text into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert dot delimited text into array.

Sample input:

```
"config.google.api.key"
```

The output I want:

```
$output['config']['google']['api']['key']
```

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please provide an [mcve] when asking a question. You're looking for the `explode` function. `$my_string = "config.google.api.key"; $my_array = explode( '.', $my_string);` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: you can try $flip = array_flip($ex);

Answer (score 0):

```
$ts = "config.google.api.key";
$ex = explode('.', $ts);
```

you can try it

Comment: Because this question is easily researched elsewhere it shouldn't be answered, but instead flagged for closure. Instead, try a comment. You should have the ability to make comments if you have >50 rep points.

Comment: This might be a correct answer, but it doesn't produce what was asked for. The output here is: `['config','google','api','key']`.

Comment: $flip = array_flip($ex);
Array
(
    [config] => 0
    [google] => 1
    [api] => 2
    [key] => 3
)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that splits on `.`, and loops over the array you have, and obtains the final index. Here it splits on `.`, which produces an array `['config','google','api','key']`, which are the keys you want to access. You can then loop this array, and chain on the subsequent index until you reach the end - then return that value.

```php
function dotToIndex($array, $string) {
    $parts = explode('.', $string);
    $element = $array;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $element = $element[$part];
    }
    return $element;
}
```

As an example, the above function with the following code

```php
$myData = [
    'config' => [
        'google' => [
            'api' => [
                'key'=> 'secret',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

echo dotToIndex($myData, "config.google.api.key");
```

Would return the index at `config.google.api.key`,

> secret

- https://3v4l.org/uAROF